# Can't Click About Element IE With Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

In my testcase i have the next locater:

```
Double Click Element    //input[@value='user1']
```

The locater is for the next snippet:

```
<tr onselectstart="listview_onselectstart(this, event)" tabindex="1" class="row altrow selected"><input class="text" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" style="width:;" value="user1">
```

This works perfect with Chrome and Firefox. When i try this with ie i see the page refresing and nothing happends. 
Doesnt ie works with javascript ? Or what can be the problem ?

Comment: why exactly are you double clicking?  What happens when you just use Click Element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has a long-standing history of extremely poor performance when it comes to XPath selectors.

Please consider using `CSS` selectors if you intend to work with IE.

In your case, `Double Click Element    css=input[value=user1]` should do the trick.